# WordPress stop loop from getting posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, loops, while-loop

This is my code from to get posts from category 1:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=1'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

but I have 3 blog posts and it is display all 3 blog posts title. i want it to only display 1 blog post. how can i do that in the while loop? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want it to only display 1 blog post. how can i do that in the while loop? thanks

Do you understand that the `while` loop is specifically used to display multiple posts?

As another user points out, you can modify the query to only select one post. However, if you're working with the main query or another subquery that you cannot change, to display a single post, you don't need a `while` loop

```
query_posts('cat=1');
if (have_posts()) {
  the_post();
  the_title();
}
else {
  echo 'sorry no posts';
}
```

If you must keep the `while` loop for whatever reason, you can `break` after the first one is displayed

```
while (have_posts()) {
  the_post();
  the_title();
  break;
}
```

---

Last remark is about your use of `if` before `while`. It makes no sense

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post() ?>
  ...
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

can be rewritten to

```
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post() ?>
  ...
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: I disagree that having an if statement before the while makes no sense. Maybe solely as an if, but and if statement is the only way to display a 'no posts found' message.

Comment: @Kenyon well that's not the code in question. I provided a remark for the existing code; no more, no less. Solving the issue you presented can be done numerous ways.

Answer (score 1):

Update the `query_posts` to use the `posts_per_page` parameter:

```
query_posts('cat=1&posts_per_page=1');
```

Which will only grab one post at a time.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#more-information